# how to write own defined function that includes an imported function?

Tags: function, module, julia

I am learning Julia programming by reading the book *Think Julia* I am including the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW619.png)

**forward** is a function in the ThinkJulia module. It acts on the Turtle() object, to move it forward. Why, after the line *using ThinkJulia* , am I getting this error. Do I have to be more specific in Julia about importing functions? I thought *using* would give me access to all functions in that particular module?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a value not to its type to `forward`, so define your function like this:

```
function forward_len(t::Turtle, d)
    forward(t, d)
end
```

and things should work

Comment: It gives me the following error/Users/lars/Desktop/Screen Shot 2020-12-17 at 08.24.01.png

Comment: it would be easier if you shared the output in the question using `\`\`\`` (triple quotes).

Comment: I tried to include an image of the output, but couldn't' figure out how. Output is this ```BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Array{Luxor.Drawing,1} at index [1] in top-level scope at turtle_me.jl:8 ....```.

Comment: Do not include an image - please copy paste the terminal output. The error you get is unrelated. It shows that this function has worked correctly, but that there is some problem in other parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear, you do not have forward method matching your parameter types.

Try 'Forward' instead of 'forward';

```
function forward_len(t::Turtle, d)
    Forward(t, d)
end
```

Source: https://juliagraphics.github.io/Luxor.jl/v0.11/turtle.html